# Почему терминал распознает слово в кавычках как команду?

Tags: bash, консоль

```
php src/cli.php exec_query -p 220419 -q "INSERT INTO storage VALUES ('cookie', '48')"
php src/cli.php exec_query -p 220419 -q "INSERT INTO 'storage' VALUES ('cookie', '48')"
```

Почему первый запрос успешно отправляет параметр `-q`, содержащийся в двойных кавычках, в PHP скрипт, а второй пример выводит ошибку:

```
bash: storage: command not found
```

Там ведь задействованы двойные кавычки только в начале и в конце, по идеи строка не должна быть прервана.

В чем проблема? Есть ли какие-то статьи на данный счет, узнать каким образом это работает?

Comment: Вы это в консоли вводите? Сильно подозреваю что нет

Comment: В терминале в докер-контейнере

Answer (score 1):

```
`
```

Такая кавычка выполняет команду.

```
'
```

Такая кавычка нужна постгресу

Comment: Так ведь такая кавычка и стоит.

Comment: Точно? Редакторы статей во всяких вордпрессах, месенжеры и ещё много чего часто подменяют кавычки на неправильные.

Comment: Да, точно. Это запущенный через консоль докер-контейнер php 7.4, сам ручками вводил...